# Error after changing name of Naturald parameter

Tags: java, database, hibernate, rename, liquibase

I have changed NaturalId column name using liquibase (from "name" to "query_name"):

```xml
<changeSet id="rename_name_to_query_name">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
        <columnExists tableName="pm_dbqueries" columnName="name" />
        <not>
            <columnExists tableName="pm_dbqueries" columnName="query_name" />
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <renameColumn
        columnDataType="varchar(40)"
        newColumnName="query_name"
        oldColumnName="name"
        tableName="pm_dbqueries"/>
</changeSet>
```

It works correctly, the name has changed... I've also updated my Entity class in java:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "pm_dbqueries", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"),
                                                      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "query_name") } )
@SequenceGenerator( name = "pm_dbqueries_seq", sequenceName = "pm_dbqueries_seq" )
public class DBQuery
{   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "pm_dbqueries_seq" )
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "query_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String queryName;

    @Column(name = "query", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 4000)
    private String query;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Long id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQueryName()
    {
        return queryName;
    }

    public void setQueryName( String queryName )
    {
        this.queryName = queryName;
    }

    public String getQuery()
    {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery( String query )
    {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

But the thing is... when I'm trying to execute this:

```
return (DBQuery) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().byNaturalId(DBQuery.class).using( "query_name", name ).load();
```

Error shows up:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No value specified for natural-id property XXX.DBQuery#queryName
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.ResolveNaturalIdEvent.<init>(ResolveNaturalIdEvent.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.ResolveNaturalIdEvent.<init>(ResolveNaturalIdEvent.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$BaseNaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.resolveNaturalId(SessionImpl.java:2466)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$NaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2581)
```

It was working fine before these changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't use code snippets for code that isn't supposed to run in the browser. Use a normal code block, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as you need to use property names not column names here. It worked earlier because there was no difference between both (name == name).

```
return (DBQuery) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().byNaturalId(DBQuery.class).using( "queryName", name ).load();
```

Comment: Please don't use code snippets for code that isn't supposed to run in the browser. Use a normal code block, instead.

Comment: @Seric Please consider to accept my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for pointing that out - did not know that so far but of course it makes perfect sense.